# What will happen if I run the command init in my Ubuntu Gnome terminal?

Tags: init

command `init` seems to be the first process running after each booting.

If I `init` in my Ubuntu Gnome terminal, will that restart my OS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're not root (and you shouldn't normally be logging in as root), you'll just get a message:

```
bash$ init
init: Need to be root
```

if you are root, you can change the current run level of the system using init (it actually runs "telinit" to make the change).

```
bash$ sudo init
init: missing runlevel
Try `init --help' for more information.
```

if you really want to reboot your system, you can do it by telling init to switch to run level six:

```
bash$ sudo init 6
```

(I'm not actually going to do this because I don't want to really reboot my machine.)

For future reference, all of this stuff is well described in the man pages.  Try running `man init` for example.  Other interesting man pages include `runlevel` and `telinit`.

Comment: Nice answer! Btw, `telinit` is actually *preferred* to change run levels.

Comment: telinit IS init, it is the same executable - just that init does some checks to see whether its PID == 1 or checks what it was invoked with to tell the difference between being in charge of all the other processes or just trying to communicate with the instance that does...